# Implementing IVertexType Interface

Tags: xna, c#, shaders, interface, vertex

In XNA, I have created a new VertexType, called it VertexPositionTextureLight which inherts the IVertexType Interface, but apparently I need to implement the member of VertexDeclartion which I cleary have:

```
struct VertexPositionTextureLight : IVertexType  {
    Vector3 position;
    Vector2 textureCoordinates;
    float light;

    public readonly static VertexDeclaration VertexDeclaration = new VertexDeclaration(new VertexElement(0, VertexElementFormat.Vector3, VertexElementUsage.Position, 0), new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 3, VertexElementFormat.Vector2, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 0), new VertexElement(sizeof(float) * 5, VertexElementFormat.Single, VertexElementUsage.TextureCoordinate, 1));

    public VertexPositionTextureLight(Vector3 position, Vector3 normal, Vector2 textureCoordinate, float light)  {
        // TODO: Use normal data
        this.position = position;
        this.textureCoordinates = textureCoordinate;
        this.light = light;
    }
}
```

I used to use this struct without inheriting the interface but since I need to call the device.DrawUserIndexedPrimitives that function wants the struct to inherit IVertexType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have this line also:

```
   VertexDeclaration IVertexType.VertexDeclaration
   {
       get { return VertexPositionTextureLight.VertexDeclaration; }
   }
```

It should work fine after that.